# how to search an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, search

suppose I have an array of names, what I want is that I want to search this particular array against the string or regular expression and then store the found matches in another array. Is this possible ? if yes then please can your give me hint ? I am new to programming.

Comment: Do you want to store the keys of the array which correspond to matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you would need to di is map the array with a callback like so:

```
array_filter($myarray,"CheckMatches");

function CheckMatches($key,$val)
{
    if(preg_match("...",$val,$match))
    {
        return $match[2];
    }
}
```

This will run the callback for every element in the array!

Updated to `array_filter`

Comment: It should be noted this *will not* return only matches, it will return all elements after _callback_ is performed on the array.

Answer (score 2):

To offer yet another solution, I would recommend using PHP's internal [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to perform the search.

```
function applyFilter($element){
  // test the element and see if it's a match to
  // what you're looking for
}

$matches = array_filter($myArray,'applyFilter');
```

As of PHP 5.3, you can use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (same code as above, just declared differently):

```
$matches = array_filter($myArray, function($element) {
  // test the element and see if it's a match to
  // what you're looking for
});
```

Answer (score 1):

well in this case you would probably do something along the lines of a `foreach` loop to iterate through the array to find what you are looking for.

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
  if ($searching_for === $value) {/* You've found what you were looking for, good job! */}
}
```

If you wish to use a PHP built in method, you can use `in_array`

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3");
if (in_array("2", $array)) echo 'Found ya!';
```

Comment: suppose there is an element in array named "google" and I want it to be selected even if someone searched for "go" or "l" or "le" or "oo". Then what sort of regular expression I need ? Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Harbhag I actually think that warrants its own question ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Store the strings in array1 
2) array2 against you want to match 
3) array3 in which you store the matches

```
$array1 = array("1","6","3");
$array2 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7");
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
  if(in_array($value,$array2))
      $array3[] = $value;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array3);
echo '</pre>';
```